# Is Convergence of Moments true in Central Limit Theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

My question is simple. Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ is an infinite sequence of Rademacher random variables (i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = -1) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1) = 1/2$). Let $S_n$ denote the random walk $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. By the central limit theorem, $n^{-1/2}S_n$ has a limiting $N(0,1)$ distribution. My question is:

Is it true that for all $k \geq 1$, $n^{-k/2}\mathbb{E}(S_n^k) \rightarrow \mathbb{E} N(0,1)^k$?

Finally, is the above true, if the $X_i$'s are general i.i.d. mean $0$, variance $1$ random variables?

Comment: You forgot independence?

Comment: For the first question, the answer is yes, since all the moments exist and the limiting distribution is normal.  For the second question, not in general, since the higher moments may not exist.

Comment: Hi  user10354138, sorry, I assume i.i.d :)

Comment: Not in general, the distributions must have uniformly small tails in some sense. But it is true for the Bernoulli trials into which the Rademacher case can be rescaled.

Comment: In general, Bernstein's extension of the central limit theorem states that this is true for all i.i.d $X_i$ with finite $k$th moment